# Custom the Navigation Item on the navigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

As the pic shows, I have successfully custom the backgroud of the navigationBar of the UINavigationController by the code:

```
UINavigationController *nav = ......
[[nav navigationBar] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_daohang"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

[image]

Now, I want to custom the item on the navigationBar (in the red circle). Is it possible to do this and how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIButton *button =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame=CGRectMake(0.0, 0, 60.0, 30.0);
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logout.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitle:@"Logout" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(logout) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem= item;
[item release];
```